# What is the recommended way to fanout in SQS lambda environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, architecture, amazon-sqs, serverless-framework

I would like to send a push notification to users in my database in a lambda environment via SQS / messaging queue architecture, in order to do that

1. I would first need to query all users in my database with push notifications enabled.
2. loop over all of them them
3. send a SQS event/message for each user.
4. let my sqs triggered lambda handle/send the push notification

Is there a better way to implement this to avoid querying a big number of users and/or looping over all the results to send a SQS message for each?

Comment: FYI you can both send and receive SQS messages in batches.

Comment: Does the SQS triggered lambda have to lookup information about the user to know where to send the notification, or is all the information gathered in step 1?

Comment: Are you [Using Amazon SNS Mobile Push](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send.html)? Are you sending exactly the same message to all users? Is this an SMS message, or a push to a mobile app on their devices? Are you sending this to _ALL_ users, or just a subset based on some logic? Is that group likely to be used repeatedly, or is the list of recipients different for every message? (Feel free to edit your question to add these details rather than answering via a comment.)

Comment: @JasonWadsworth all gathered in Step1, the SQS triggered lambda simply calls the PushNotification service with the received info

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm not using SNS, I'm using firebase cloud messaging. Its a push notification to a mobile app. It is the same message yes, and only to a subset of users based on some logic. The list of recipients might differ because its event based and what the user preferences are.

Comment: Since you have all the data upfront the only question I'd have is whether there is value in the SQS portion. SQS does allow you to send batch messages, whereas SNS does not, so that could be important. Also, since the service you are sending to is external (not SNS) it could be valuable to have the retry of the lambda on a record by record basis. In the end I think this is a reasonable pattern.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth my main reasoning behind using SQS is to defer the logic of sending push notifications to be handled by multiple lambdas for performance/load reasons as well as better error handling as opposed to waiting for (n) number of requests to be made in parallel via a `Promise.all`.

My SQS setup is also set to retry sending the message and thus retriggering the lambda a couple of times if it fails before finally moving it to a Dead Letter Queue.

So my concern is if its really worth using SQS to defer the logic if I have to loop & wait for n requests made in parallel to SQS anyway

Comment: Does firebase cloud messaging allow you to specify all recipients at once, or do you need to send the notification in batches?

Comment: if this a continuose process like few hunfred messages are sent alteast every seconds which can go upto millions of messages per second then I would recommend to use ec2 with sqs+eb worker. Use redis or ec2 memory for caching of frequent data set. set up autoscaling in eb worker to min:2 max: n depending on the load. You can send millions of messags in minutes.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible with your current architecture, but what you really need is, instead of a per user notification, a per channel notification. Then, instead of querying your database for all the users with notifications enabled and sending messages one-by-one, you'd just add them to the channel when they sign up for notifications and send a single message to the channel.

Answer (score 3):

I would take a slightly different approach here, but similar.

1. Query the database for the users
2. Loop over the users
3. Send one messages to SQS for a batch of records to send, and use the `SendMessageBatch` operation of SQS to send them. So batches of batches. Each batch of messages would have several "users" to send to, not just one. This will should increase your performance because a batch will require fewer lambda invocations.
4. Lambda handles SQS messages (probably more than one), and each SQS message results in sending many push notifications. In the case of Firebase I believe there is a way to send batches, which is even better. Even without that you can send several messages at once using a `Promise.all` type logic.

With this structure you can send a very large number of messages really quickly, and probably a lot cheaper. Imagine you need to send to 1M users. If you send batches of 100, in batches of 25 to SQS, then you have 2,500 messages per call to SQS. That would mean 400 calls to SQS, far better than even the 40K you'd have to make if you sent single messages in batches of 25.

On the receiving side, even if you throttled the SQS integration to 1 message per invocation you'd have 10,000 lambda invocations. If you assume even 1s per invocation, and 1000 concurrent invocations, it would take 10 seconds (likely less). If you send one message per user you'd have to make 1M lambda invocations. If you assume each invocation takes 100ms then you can send 10/second, so with 1000 concurrent executions it would take 100 seconds. In reality the numbers are probably even better than that for the batch version, especially if you don't limit it to 1 message at a time.

**Edit**
Based on the comments the question seemed to be a bit more about the first part of the process. With that in mind I'd suggest the following options.

1. If you find yourself needing to address the same large groups repeatedly most messaging services (Firebase and SNS for sure) support some sort of topic subscription model. Given that these are push notifications you can subscribe a device to the topic in code. What this ultimately leads to is one messages sent from your code to the messaging service. The service handles the rest. This is probably the preferred solution for anything that has mass recipients, especially if you can know the recipients up front. This even works for dynamic topics. For example, consider a situation where a person comments on a post. Any new comment on that post should send a message to everyone who has commented on that post. You can create a topic on the fly when the post is created, and add recipients to the topic as they comment. If a user wishes to stop receiving messages you can remove the user from the topic.
2. If you don't know the recipients up front the above solution is a solid solution. However, if you are concerned with Lambda timeouts on the first two steps I'd modify slightly. I would take advantage of AWS Step Functions and page the data in the lambda. Lambda will tell you, via the `context` object supplied in the invocation, how much time is remaining. You can check that periodically to determine if you should exit the lambda and pass to the step function the current paging information. The step function can pass that paging information back into the lambda, which should be coded to accept the paging information as part of the request, and continue from that point if supplied.

Comment: While this provides an optimisation it doesn't really answer the crux of the question, is there a better way than to query all the data, loop, and queue. Perhaps a different architecture to prepare for this event earlier, or some solution that hardens against lambda timeouts or errors?

Comment: I see what you mean. I'll add some comments/options for optimizing the front end portion.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an additional piece in your application architecture,
I personally prefer to avoid using the Primary database for heavy querying,
assuming you have a large user base.

I will suggest maintaining your user list in a Search Engine like ElasticSearch or CloudSearch, or a simple table with just the user list in AWS DynamoDb or create a Read Replica of your DB.
To no confuse you, use a Search Engine(first choice) or an AWS DynamoDb

This will avoid creating pressure on your database when you query the read specialty datastore and won't affect other modules in operation
And it's way fast to query this way

Step 2: loop over all of them them

Step 3: batch send messages to SQS using its SendMessageBatch method like Jason is suggesting

Step 4: Based on your SQS setting, you may process multiple messages on your Lambda function

Comment: This just moves scanning one database for another. The search component is a good recommendation to target subsets of users but the question is about the best way to extract and load to a queue.

Comment: @noetix I wondering how to avoid that loop, the search will make things faster for the query issue, but the loop hmm, something interesting to think over this weekend haha

Comment: I think the answer lies in subscribing people to channel(s) if you want to send the same message to groups (architecture solve), or distribute loading over time and query the database in batches. Both have their pros and cons that I had hoped the bounty would surface.

Comment: That can be done AWS SNS as it offers 10 million subscriptions per topic, but the application will somehow need to force its users to accept the SNS subscription, but then I believe each email to be sent requires a custom message, with SNS it'll be more like a common message use case